# ViewModel property not getting updated on changing TextBox text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a TextBox in a UserControl which is binded to a property in the MainWindow's ViewModel.

Now when I type something in the Textbox, it updates the property in the viewmodel but if I change Textbox's text in code behind, the viewmodel property isn't updating.

Actually the textbox is getting the value from FileDialog which is opened when I click the button, so Textbox is getting its text from code behind.

UserControl XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxFileOrFolder" Text="{Binding FolderOrFileName}" Grid.Row="1" Width="200" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonRun" Content="Run" Click="ButtonRun_OnClick" Width="200" Height="100" Margin="10"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

UserControl code behind

```
private void ButtonRun_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxFileOrFolder.Text = "FileName" + new Random().Next();
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    { }

    private string folderOrFileName;

    public string FolderOrFileName
    {
        get { return folderOrFileName; }
        set
        {
            if (folderOrFileName!=value)
            {
                folderOrFileName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the property changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    # endregion
}
```

Comment: Just curious: That "[CallerMemberName]" phrase is unknown to me. Is that some magic compiler hullabaloo from a vs version > 2010?

Comment: @Udontknow It was introduced with .NET 4.5 and basically passes the calling member’s name at compile time. So it’s perfect for implementing INPC. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but if I change Textbox's text in code behind, the viewmodel property isn't updating.

That’s because if you set the `Text` property of the text box in the code-behind, you are overwriting the binding. So while you update the view, the link to your view model is gone, so there is nothing that will update it. And also, when the view model update the values, the view also will not be updated.

To solve this, simply don’t set properties that have a binding in the code-behind.

Instead of handling the button event in the code-behind and updating the view, you should have your button command bind to your view model and update the `FolderOrFileName` in the view model.

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you binding to `Text` property you should set property in the ViewModel to change value of `TextBox`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainViewModel _vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vm = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = _vm;
    }

    private void ButtonRun_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _vm.FolderOrFileName = "FileName" + new Random().Next();
    }
}
```

In your case you should use command to modify data.

1) You should create class which inherit from `ICommand`:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute,
                   Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

2) Next you should create command in ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ChangeFileName = new DelegateCommand(OnChangeFileName);
    }

    public ICommand ChangeFileName { get; private set; }

    private void OnChangeFileName(object param)
    {
        FolderOrFileName = "FileName" + new Random().Next();
    }

    private string folderOrFileName;
    ...
```

3) And finally you should add binding to `Button.Command` property in View:

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonRun" Content="Run" Command="{Binding ChangeFileName}" Width="200" Height="100" Margin="10"></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your binding is set up as "TwoWay" - UI -> VM and VM -> UI

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxFileOrFolder" Text="{Binding FolderOrFileName, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" Width="200" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>
```

Comment: The default binding mode for a TextBox is TwoWay.

Comment: Been awhile since I've done WPF - though I usually found specifying Mode was much more readable down the line.